# Stop VBA from halting when an IE pop up box is opened and close the pop up alert box

Tags: excel, automation, ui-automation, webautomation, vba

This infuriating pop up box is besetting me since 2 months ..some one help me get over this.

I wrote a code to click an anchor link in my web page when this link is clicked it usually navigates to next page. If the data is notprovided properly on the page  on clicking the link it opens a pop up box and there my VBA code stops until i click ok on the pop up box(Why the hell my VBA code stops here ?).
Further i need to close this button using my VBA and correct the data and click link again.
i have tried following solutions and they seem nothing much of a panacea for me.
1. Removing onclick attribute (http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/426740-using-visual-basic-applications-close-internet-explorer-message-box-popup.html ) This doesnt work even if it works its nt suitable to my case
2. Sending keys-Im nt sure why the people even posted this as a solution.my code stops soon after the link is clicked and code never reaches to the line send keys until the pop up i sclosed manually.

3.Opening another istance of excel just before clicking  linkand run code in the new excel to close the pop up box and close it(http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=1146) This seems to work but i need to click that link almost 500 timies this makes the code to open excel sheet every now and then which looks clumsy,time consuming process consuming and not feasible
Can some one please tell me a way to close the dialog box, why the hell some one invented this alert box.

Here is my code

```
while x>1

'Fill the details in webpage 

 Set TDelements = IEfr1.getElementsByTagName("a")
     For Each TDelement In TDelements
       If TDelement.innerText = "Next" Then
        ' TDelement.Focus
        ' Call BeginTimer(500, IE.hwnd)

       TDelement.Click '//this makes the alert box fire and code halts here until the box is closed

        'TDelement.setAttribute "onclick", "return true"
      TDelement.FireEvent ("onClick")
       TDelement.FireEvent ("onsubmit")
       ' Application.Wait (10000)
       While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

       End If

      Next
```

loop

Comment: You need to open the excel instance as VBA cannot work asynchronously. But you to open it only once and in the above loop run the macro which will close the popup every time just before your page navigates.

Comment: @SiddharthRout   Did you go throgh the code given on the page http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=1146 i dont think there is a possibility that i could keep open the excel and call the code in it when ever it is required.if we keep the excel open and call a method before clicking on the link in the new excel, the pointer wouldnot return to the orginal called  method  until the method in the other excel is finished. how am ever gonna get back ..can you tell me how to call the method in other excel without having to wait for the method in other excel to be completed?

Comment: As I mentioned in my prev comment, you need to open another excel instance. You can do that by `createobject` and then open the 2nd workbook in that instance. can you share the url you are trying to process? And Yes, I saw the link that you mentioned.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Hi Thanks a load for the reply, i know how to create a new instance and open new work bookbut problem is if im calling a function like close_popup(next line would be to click on the link for which pop up opens)which is in the other workbook, the pointer will point to the close_popup method and keeps excuting the pointer would return when the method is completed and then the code in the first book resumes to click the link which is of no use, i want both of the methods in two workbooks to work independently. -Sry that i cant give you the link due to security concerns.pls help me

Comment: @SiddharthRout Helppppppppppppppppp

Comment: Wish i could.... `Sry that i cant give you the link due to security concerns.pls help me –  nothingisimpossible Nov 7 at 5:04`